# Javascript button ceases to write to texarea once user has added text

Tags: javascript, html, button, textarea

I am trying to make a simple text editing box so that I can eventually post text to another section of a website. I'm attempting to make buttons to make text bold, italicized, add a code box etc, (hence `insertAdjacentHTML` not `insertAdjacentText`) but I decided to just start making sure I could get plain text to print to a textarea.
I have achieved this easily but now my question becomes how do I make it so that the button still affects the text area after a user has added text to it? the code below will happily type out "hello"'s up until you click on the textarea, and from that point on it refuses to and I can't figure out why.

```js
window.hello = function(textarea) {
  var obj = document.getElementById("text");
  obj.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'hello');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="hello()">hello</button>
  <form>
    <p></p>
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) a textarea can contain only ***Character data***.

This is the reason because you cannot use ***insertAdjacentHTML*** and instead you can use the ***value***.

If you need to add text in bold or ...  you can use a contenteditable div element.

The snippet:

```js
window.helloDiv = function() {
  var obj = document.getElementById("textDiv");
  obj.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'hello');
};
window.helloTxtArea = function() {
  var obj = document.getElementById("textTxtArea");
  obj.value += 'hello';
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="helloDiv()">helloDiv</button>
<button onclick="helloTxtArea()">helloTextArea</button>

<form>
    <p></p>
    <div id="textDiv" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <textarea id="textTxtArea" contenteditable="true"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: this looks spot on and solves the issue nicely and goes above and beyond to help me with editing HTML later on. Thank you!